# Reload nginx config from salt state, only if the configtest passes

Tags: nginx, salt-stack

I've recently written a salt state which handles the nginx config for a number of servers from some static variables in pillar. I wanted to roll this out to all the servers, but before I did this I wanted to make sure before the config is applied on a server it has first been tested.

Nginx has an inbuilt configtest which I use frequently on command line, and I found that salt has an nginx module which can be used to run configtest.

I have the following in my state file:

```
reload-nginx:
  service.running:
    - enabled: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - pkg: nginx
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/*
      - file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This should reload nginx if the config files change, or if the nginx install is upgraded/changed. I believe I can run a config test using the following in my state file (untested):

```
nginx-config-test:
  module.run:
    - name: nginx.configtest
```

And I believe if I add this state to the watch in the reload-nginx state it would reload if the configtest passed.

However, I want the reload to happen only if either of the config files have changed **AND** the config test passes, or if nginx changes **AND** the configtest passes. I see I can use onlyif to run a state if **ALL** of the things are True, and from experience you can' have multiple uses of the same method (so I can't have 3 different onlyif's - correct me if I am wrong).

But I don't see any way to reload nginx only if the config files have changed (or nginx has been updated) and the configtest has passed.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer; it seems you need to use module.wait rather than module.run for the watch property to work as expected. I didn't catch that first time around, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the reload state watch the config-test state; have the config-test state watch the config files state and the pkg state. The test will only run if something changes, and the reload will only occur if the test runs and passes.

Caveat: Structurally this will work, but I've never used nginx.configtest, so I can't promise it behaves the way you think.

You will also need to use module.wait rather than module.run; watch statements don't work with .run. Reference [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html).

So that becomes:

```
reload-nginx:
  service.running:
    - name: nginx
    - enable: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - module: nginx-config-test

nginx-config-test:
  module.wait:
    - name: nginx.configtest
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/*
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the question with what I have found using your suggestion. Not sure if what I have done with the for loop causes the following part not to work. Any further suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try this in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

For services like ssh without a salt module method like `.configtest` this can be done manually like so:

```
reload-sshd:
    service.running:
        - name: ssh
        - reload: True
        - enable: True
        - watch:
            - cmd: test-sshd-config

test-sshd-config:
    cmd.wait:
        - name: sshd -t
        - stateful: True
        - watch:
            - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).